# Dynamically construct SQL search query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to build a search query based on the input from users, but I am having problems with the `AND` and `WHERE` keywords. Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {

    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM candidate ';
    $where = array();

    $criteria = array('gender' => $gender, 'level' => $level, 'status' => $status);
    foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
        if ($value !== 'all') {
            $where[] = $key . ' = ' . $value;
        }
    }

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => gender = masculine
    [1] => level = low
    [2] => status = future
)
```

If no option is selected, it defaults to 'all' and it is excluded from the `$where[]`.

I need to achieve this, or anything similar:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WHERE gender = masculine
    [1] => AND level = low
    [2] => AND status = future
)
```

The `WHERE` must be appended only if one or more options have been selected and the `AND` must be appended only if two or more options have been selected.

In the code I am using I have 9 search inputs. To keep it clear I only displayed three in the snippet. Can you please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:I think you need the whereClause in string not in array,here you can choose any one from two and remove the other one.

```
<?php 
$where=array();$flag=0;// use flag to identify the where/and
 $whereClause="";
 $criteria = array('gender' => "masculine", 'level' => "low", 'status' => "future");
    foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
        if ($value !== 'all') {
            if($flag == 0){
             $where[] = " WHERE " .$key . ' = ' . $value;//if you need array
             $whereClause='WHERE '.$key . ' = "' . $value.'"';//if you need string
            }else{
             $where[] = " AND " .$key . ' = ' . $value;
             $whereClause .=' AND '.$key . ' = "' . $value.'"';
            }
             $flag++;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($where);
    echo "</pre>";

   echo $whereClause;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it efficient if I go with your previous answer and add this: `$query .= implode("", $where);`?

Comment: implode is better than string concatenation  but in your case it will not make too much difference you can use either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put one incrementer (`$inc`) and then put the conditions as:

```
$inc=1;
foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
        if ($value !== 'all') {
            if($inc==1){
            $where[] = 'Where '.$key . ' = ' . $value.'';
            }else{
            $where[] = 'AND '.$key . ' = ' . $value.'';
            }

            $inc++;
    }
}
```

In My view there is one more clean way of achiving this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {

    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM candidate ';
    $where = array("Where 1=1");

    $criteria = array('gender' => $gender, 'level' => $level, 'status' => $status);
    foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
        if ($value !== 'all') {
            $where[] = 'AND '.$key . ' = ' . $value.' ';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM candidate ';
 $where='';
 $criteria = array('gender' => $gender, 'level' => $level, 'status' => $status);
 foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
    if ($value !== 'all') {
        if($where=='')
            $where='WHERE '.$key . ' = ' . $value;
        else
            $where.=' AND '.$key . ' = ' . $value;

    }
}
$query.=$where; //final query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple switch statement too

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {

        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $level = $_POST['level'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM candidate ';
        $where = array();

        $criteria = array('gender' => $gender, 'level' => $level, 'status' => $status);
        foreach ($criteria as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($value !== 'all')
            {
                switch ($key)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        $query = " WHERE " .$key . ' = ' . $value;
                        break;
                    }

                    case 2:
                    {
                        $query = " AND " .$key . ' = ' . $value;
                        break;
                    }

                    case 3:
                    {
                        $query = " AND " .$key . ' = ' . $value;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                $where[] = $query;
            }
        }

    }
```